# Есть ли Jabber (xmpp) клиент с возможностью отправки изображения из буфера обмена?

Tags: xmpp

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли Jabber (xmpp) клиент с возможностью отправки изображения из буфера обмена?
В качестве сервера использую openfire

Спасибо заранее за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

На андроид есть Convesations, который расшаривает файлы из галереи проводника. Существуют так консольные клиенты, которые отправляют файлы откуда угодно, хоть из буфера, хоть с удаленного сервера, но это под линукс

Answer (score 0):

Для линукс в GUI и Win: Pidgin. (Вы не указывает, под какую ОС необходим клиент - поэтому такой ответ)